# Sphinx: Initialize Real Time Index

Tags: sphinx

I would like to migrate one of the sphinx index into real time.  However, rt index doesn't take a source and its initialization is kinda messy.  Is there a way to migrate existing index into real time without a lot of scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment no official way exists. Only custom solutions. In this interesting [document](http://pro100pro.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/Presentation-sphinx-RT-indexes.pdf) (PDF) there is one of the ways mentioned:

```
mysqldump -uroot blog users > users_dump.sql
mysql -P9306 < users_dump.sql
```

Regards.

Answer (score 7):

I am glad that my [presentation](http://pro100pro.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/Presentation-sphinx-RT-indexes.pdf) was helpful, but now Sphinx has new command which help migrate from original to real-time indexes: [attach index](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-attach-index)

It is simple as:

```
ATTACH INDEX diskindex TO RTINDEX rtindex
```

BTW, I have wrote a blog post which describe [attach index](http://www.ivinco.com/blog/converting-sphinx-original-indexes-to-real-time-indexes/) command in details.